# Need to parse a log file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a log file that contains a lot of text, some of it is useless. In this log there are some lines that are important for me. The pattern for those lines are:

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
```

The NEEDED keyword could be found on all lines that are important for me. The keyword between [] is the one important for me. I need to create a list of all those strings, without repeating them.

I've done this on Python, but looks like on the machine I want to run the script there is no Python available, so I need to rework the script in bash. I know only basic stuff in bash and I'm not able to find a solution for my problem.

The Python script I've used is:

```
import sys
import re


def testForKeyword(keyword, line):
    findStuff = re.compile(r"\b%s\b" % keyword, \
                                   flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    if findStuff.search(line):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Get filename argument
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("USAGE: python libraryParser.py <log_file.log>")
    sys.exit(-1)

file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

sharedLibraries = []
for line in file:
    if testForKeyword("NEEDED", line):
        libraryNameStart = line.find("[") + 1
        libraryNameFinish = line.find("]")

        libraryName = line[libraryNameStart:libraryNameFinish]

        # No duplicates, only add if it does not exist
        try:
            sharedLibraries.index(libraryName)
        except ValueError:
            sharedLibraries.append(libraryName)

for library in sharedLibraries:
    print(library)
```

Can you please help me solving this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One solution would be to pull out all lines containing "NEEDED" using `grep`, then use `cut` to split the line on square brackets and then `uniq` so remove any duplicates.

Comment: what do you want? a list of the .so?

Comment: what did your "algorithm" in Python look like? You need to show some work for us to help with. Think about what steps are happening in your python code. Then a question like "here are the steps I'm doing in python, 1. .... 2 ....  3...., what are the equivalent or best practices techniques in shell?" would show that your not just looking for some free consulting. (Edit your question, don't reply in the comments ; -). Good luck.

Comment: Which version of Bash?  bash 3 onwards supports REs similar to Python (extended REs) as well as captures.  You might be able to reuse your Python RE (assuming you used it)

Comment: yes, that correct, I need to create a list of unique .so's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `awk` assuming `infile` with data of the question:

```
awk '
    $2 ~ /NEEDED/ { 
        lib = substr( $NF, 2, length($NF) - 2 ); 
        libs[ lib ] = 1;
    } 
    END { 
        for (lib in libs) { 
            printf "%s\n", lib;
        } 
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
libc.so.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
libgcc_s.so.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
ld.so.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
libm.so.6
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '/NEEDED/ {print $2}' data.txt | sort | uniq
ld.so.1
libc.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libm.so.6
```

awk only:

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '/NEEDED/ {save[$5]++}END{ for (i in save) print i}' data.txt
libc.so.6
libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
ld.so.1
```

Simplification of your python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

libs = []

with open("data.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if "NEEDED" in line:
            libs.append(line.split()[4])

for i in set(libs):
    print i
```

Bash solution (without unique libs)

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='][' read -a array
do
    echo ${array[1]}
done < data.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With `grep` and `coreutils`:

```
grep NEEDED infile | grep -o '\[[^]]*\]' | tr -d '][' | sort | uniq
```

Output:

```
ld.so.1
libc.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libm.so.6
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk -F '[' ' /NEEDED/ { print $NF } ' file_name | sed 's/]//' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '/NEEDED/ {gsub("[][]", ""); print $5}' < /tmp/1.txt  | sort -u
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a `uniq` command that also does the required pre-`sort' ;-). Good luck to all

Answer (score 1):

If you have your logs in a file called "log.txt", you can get it:

```
grep "(NEEDED)" log.txt | awk -F"\[" '{print substr($2,0,length($2));}' - | sort -u
```

Using sort -u you will not get duplicated lines.

Answer (score 1):

sed solution might be:

```
sed -e '/(needed)/!d' -e 's/\(.*\[\)\|\(\]$\)//g' INPUTFILE
```

*Note*, if you are on Windows, de proper way is this:

```
sed -e '/(needed)/!d' -e 's/\(.*\[\)\|\(\].$\)//g' INPUTFILE
```

1. the first `-e` part deletes every line that does not match `(needed)`
2. the second deletes everything till the last `[` and the last `]` (and on windows the `\r` (carriage return) before the `\n` but that's not a problem since the output printed properly...